# What is the prebid member id?

Tags: prebid

For prebid-server [the example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/appnexus.md) shows `json='{"pageOpts": {"member": 958,"invCode": "ast_guaranteed_prios_1","...`, especially the `member` value. Without setting this, requests to https://ib.adnxs.com/ut/v3
 fail with

> {"error":"Could not find valid member in request"}

What is `pageOpts.member`? Which value should it be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave is not for prebid-server, it is for accessing Appnexus directly. In order to setup prebid server you should follow [their AMP instructions here](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/show-prebid-ads-on-amp-pages.html). Also, to debug the auction on the client side you can add: &debug=1 to the url that sends the request to prebid-server, it generally is prebid.adnxs.com/pbs/v1/openrtb2/amp?, however that will be different if you use your own hosting.